# Recursive Fibonacci calculation with caching - can't find an error

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I wrote a simple function to calculate fibonacci numbers, but it goes into infinite loop and crashes. I can't seem to find what is the problem here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int number, int *cache);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int cache[20] = {0};
    int result = fib (3, cache);
    printf("%d ", result);
}

int fib(int number, int *cache)
{
    if (number == 0) return 0;
    if (number == 1) return 1;

    if (cache[number] != 0) return cache[number];

    int result = fib(number - 1, cache) + (number - 2, cache);
    cache[number] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say? And why would you declare `cache` as `static`???

Comment: Run it in a debugger, and check the values when the crash happens. Or step through it line by line.

Comment: `int result = fib(number - 1, cache) + (number - 2, cache);`
Did you forget to write `fib` in front of second `(`?

Comment: @bash.d static was the remnant of my debugging. removed it

Comment: Tried your program, with and without the missing `fib` call. Works fine (wrong result with the missing call though, but no infinite looping).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this line contains error

```
int result = fib(number - 1, cache) + (number - 2, cache);
```

`fib` is missing. It should be

```
int result = fib(number - 1, cache) + fib(number - 2, cache);
```

Comment: @HirenPandya I tested it (with the correction) and it works and the program print 2 as result

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @MOHAMED's answer, you only initialize `cache[0]`, the other elements can contain arbitrary garbage (it really is undefined behaviour to access them). Works as intended ;-)

Comment: initializing array of any size to {0} fills all other elements with zeroes